# Typescript union type not working

Tags: types, typescript, typescript1.4

I have the following classes:

```
export interface ISimpleUser {
    id: number;
    full_name: string;
}


export interface IMember extends ng.resource.IResource<IMember> {
    id: number;
    project: number;
    user: number|ISimpleUser;
    skills: ISkill[];
    about: string;
    accepted: Boolean;

    updated: Date;
    created: Date;
}
```

At some point I want to iterate over an arroy of members like in the following example:

```
        return angular.forEach<resources.IMember>(this.project.members,
            (member: resources.IMember) => {
                return member.user.id == user.id;
            }).length > 0;
```

But I get this error:

```
error TS2339: Property 'id' does not exist on type 'number | ISimpleUser'
```

Don't know what is wrong exactly. I see other parts of the code working with the union types.

Thanks.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You will need to do some type checking and casting to handle this scenario:

```
(member: resources.IMember) => {
  return member.user.id == user.id;
  if (typeof (member.user) === 'number') {
    return member.user == user.id;
  } else {
    return (<ISimpleUser>member.user).id == user.id;
  }
}).length > 0;
```

Just because you know the possible types at code/design time does not mean that the compiles code knows types at run time. So you can check the type of `member.user` to see if it is a number then conditionally do your comparison.

Answer (score 3):

The `number` type in TypeScript (and JavaScript) doesn't have an `id` property.  To use a property on a union type without protective type checking (to bust the union type), the properties must have the same name and type.  For example if the `user` property were defined like this:

```
user: IOtherThing|ISimpleUser;
```

and `IOtherThing` had an `id` property, then it would work.

I am guessing, but you probably will have to do something like this:

```
var getId = (id: number | IMember) => {
        if (typeof id === "number") {
            return id;
        } else {
            return id.id;
        }
    };
return angular.forEach<resources.IMember>(this.project.members,
    (member: resources.IMember) => {
        return getId(member.user.id) === getId(user);
    }).length > 0;
```

Comment: if user is a number then this code will not work `getId(member.user.id)` as there is no property on id on a number

Answer (score 3):

Typescript doesn't know how to deal with `member.user` in your foreach, you need to put the logic in a `typeof if` statement:

```
return angular.forEach<resources.IMember>(this.project.members, (member: resources.IMember) => {
    var memberUser = member.user;

    if(typeof memberUser === 'number'){
        return memberUser === user.id;
    } else if (typeof member.user === 'object') {
        return memberUser.id === user.id;
    }
}).length > 0;
```

By using the `typeof` TypeScript can infer which type you want to use at which point.

Alternatively if you know your list only contains `ISimpleUser`, then you could cast the `member.user` i.e `var memberUser = <ISimpleUser> member.user;`