# How to use variable defined as one of multiple types against array of one of those types in Typescript?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

Here is a minimalist example showing the core of the problem, hope it helps understanding my case

```
interface Type1 {value1: number};
interface Type2 {value2: string};

let variable: Type1|Type2;

let variableType1List: Type1[];
let variableType2List: Type2[];

let usingType1: boolean = true;
let variableListPosition: number;

if (usingType1) {
    variable = {value1: 5};
} else {
    variable = {value2: "hello world"};
}

if (usingType1) {
    variableListPosition = variableType1List.indexOf(variable);
} else {
    variableListPosition = variableType2List.indexOf(variable);
}
```

I get error *Argument of type 'Type1 | Type2' is not assignable to parameter of type 'Type1'. Property 'value1' is missing in type 'Type2' but required in type 'Type1'.* on a row

```
variableListPosition = variableType1List.indexOf(variable);
```

and I get error *Argument of type 'Type1 | Type2' is not assignable to parameter of type 'Type2'. Property 'value2' is missing in type 'Type1' but required in type 'Type2'.* on a row

```
variableListPosition = variableType2List.indexOf(variable);
```

One thing is this can be solved by creating the parent class with shared logic and then define children for the specific types. But I am still curious if something like this is possible, because from time to time I would like to allow passing variable of multiple types into my functions and then work with them a little differently to make my classes easier to use for other programmers.

Thank you for your response!

Comment: Is the compiler expected to understand that the type of `show` is correlated to the type of `this.props.type`?  What happens if `this.props.type` is `RelatedShowTypes.LIVE` but you call `this.getShowPositionIndex(record)`?  Maybe your class should actually be generic?  In any case I don't think this is quite enough info for you to get a good answer.  Could you try to produce a [mcve] that doesn't depend on other code to demonstrate?  Preferably one that can be pasted into a standalone IDE like [the unofficial playground](https://typescript-play.js.org/)?

Comment: @jcalz I have added minimalist and abstract example, do you thing it helps clearing my case?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Typescript union type not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30621139/typescript-union-type-not-working)

Comment: @MaazSyedAdeeb I think its not quite similar, because I am using two completely different interfaces, but example showin in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30621139/typescript-union-type-not-working uses number|interface. You can typecheck number, but cannot officially typecheck interface (i know I can write my own function, but thats not something Typescript understands). I just tested it.

Comment: If I were you, I'd just use `as any` to mute the error.

Comment: @hackape That silences the problem, but I cant tell my fellow programmers, what types can that variable hold. Most of the use cases are for method parameters and if that is set to any, nobody knows what type he can or can not put into that method.

Comment: @WaxCage I mean `variableType1List.indexOf(variable as any)`, not `let variable: any`.

Comment: `variable` can be one of the 2 types, understood. `variableType1List` only holds element of `Type1`, understood. What goes wrong is TS's stock typings think `.indexOf()` should accept only param of that type. This is like requiring `isString()` to take only `string` as param. It's a freaking tester function, should be able to test on anything. So `as any` is the best solution in my eye.

Comment: @hackape Please write your solution as answer and I will upvote and accept this one, its a very good solution. Event better solution is use variableType1List.indexOf(variable as Type1)!

Comment: @WaxCage answer posted

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think this is a problem on your part. Every typing makes sense in your example. What goes wrong is TS's stock typings `.indexOf()` accepts **only** param of the array's element type, which is clearly an overkilling constraint to me.

It's like requiring `isString()` to take only `string` as param, I mean, if I know it's a `string` then I don't need to call it at all. Likewise `.indexOf` is often used as a testing method, and it's perfectly fine to use it against anything.

My suggestion, just use `as any` to get around it.

```js
variableListPosition = variableType2List.indexOf(variable as any);
```

Alternatively you can also amend TS stock lib's typing with declaration merging. Thankfully `indexOf` is a function, you can add-in an overload signature without problem.

```js
declare global {
    interface Array<T> {
        indexOf(searchElement: any, fromIndex?: number): number
    }
}
```

Comment: As I mentioned in comment above, the best solution from my perspective is using variableType1List.indexOf(variable as Type1) and variableType2List.indexOf(variable as Type2) respectively. But I wouldn't be able to find out without your answer. Thank you!

Answer (score -1):

We'd need more insights of your problem but, something as follows will probably help:

```
interface Dummy {
   type1Value?: Type1
   type2Value?: Type2
}
```

You can change your variable to use this Dummy type. It'd mean some changes in other parts of your code but semantically this should work just fine

Comment: Does not solve the problem - gives Argument of type 'Dummy' is not assignable to parameter of type 'Type1'.
  Property 'value1' is optional in type 'Dummy' but required in type 'Type1'